# Appcelerator Titanium + Foursquare oAuth2

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, foursquare

I would like to make an Appcelerator application using Foursquare 
oAuth2. Is there any example I could follow? Or any of you have 
implemented something similar? 
Thanks,
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [KitchenSink Foursquare.js](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/foursquare.js) yet?

Comment: thanks for your reply Brian. Unfortunately, the example does not use OAuth, it is necessary enter username and password in the application this is something I wanted to avoid. :(

Comment: whoops sorry about that, it's twitter but it should work the same way using oAuth. http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/07/twitter-oauth-implementation-for-titanium-mobile.html